# Check for data prefix in the mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to write a Mysql function which will check for the feature entry in the SQL table named FeatureEntry. Data in the FeatureEntry will be like:

```
    mysql> select * from FeatureEntry ;
+----+------+---------+
| Id | Code | Feature |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | 121  | test1   |
|  2 | 122  | test2   |
|  3 | 123  | test3   |
|  5 | 125  | test5   |
|  6 | 126  | test6   |
|  7 | 127  | test7   |
|  8 | 128  | test8   |
+----+------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Function will pass number1 as argument and return 0 if the number is prefixed with any of the Code entry made in the FeatureEntry table.
Else function will return 0;
For example when I call the mysql function check_for_feature_code(1215676767), it should return 0 as it contains the prefix 121 which is present in the table.

```
mysql> select check_for_feature_code(1215676767);
+-------------------------------+
| check_for_feature_code(12156767671) |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

If I call the function check_for_feature_code(67675676767), it should return 1 as it doesn't match the prefix with codes in the table.

PS -- Codes are strings not integers.

Comment: I dont believe theres enough information to make this enough for people to answer.  You've said the function will pass "number1" as argument and return 0 if the number is prefixed with any of the code entry.. Can you give some examples of what you've tried and an example of parameters you expected to work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to call my function like: `mysql> select check_for_feature_code(12122222);
+-------------------------------+
| check_for_feature_code(12122222) |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Are your codes integers or strings?

Comment: @rajnsit how do u create such nice table structure? manually or from some site +1

Comment: @diEcho -- thanks, I just copy pasted from mysql opened in putty and selected the format as "code" while pasting..

Comment: are the codes of some fixed length 3, or any length ?

Comment: Codes are variable length strings. They can be : *121*, *121#, *12231# etc .... Number passed can be like *12231#67676767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function (tested with your posted dataset in MySQL 5.1) that returns 0 if a given number is prefixed with a Code from the FeatureEntry table, otherwise it returns 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `check_for_feature_code`(`num_in` INT)
 RETURNS TINYINT
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 READS SQL DATA
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT 'Checks for a feture code prefix'
BEGIN
 DECLARE is_featured INT;
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO is_featured FROM FeatureEntry WHERE Code = SUBSTR(CONVERT(num_in, CHAR), 1, LENGTH(Code));
 IF is_featured = 0 THEN RETURN 1;
 END IF;
 RETURN 0;
END;
```

This is now working for a variable length code prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the code when Code string is of variable length. It is not of 3 letters only.

Comment: OK.  Please try to be more clear in your requirements (and data examples). I've changed the code to allow for variable length code prefixes.

Comment: We dont know the size of the code prefix put in the table, we will pass only one number in the table. We need to go with REGEXP after browsing for each code. We need to exit as soon as we get the 1st matching code and it will be better if we know the Id of the matching code also.

Comment: You don't need to know the size of the code prefix, because the code finds this out for itself.  I think that I've answered your question twice and now you are changing it again.  You can change the SELECT in the function to get the Id instead of COUNT and add an ORDER BY and LIMIT cause.  I think that you should be prepared to do _some_ work yourself now.